# Tensorflow 2.3+ build with CUDA 11.0 on Windows

Tags: windows, tensorflow, build, bazel

When trying to build Tensorflow from `r2.3` branch or from master (commit `cf49bfdb2a177cb2c39834ff3e8ae6fd9dca2ad9`) with CUDA 11.0 and CUDNN 8 I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: D:/libs/ai_ml/tf2020-07-28/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/BUILD:319:1: undeclared inclusion(s) in rule '//tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda:cudnn_stub':
this rule is missing dependency declarations for the following files included by 'tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudnn_stub.cc':
  'tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudnn_version.h'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 496.046s, Critical Path: 172.61s
INFO: 4679 processes: 4679 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I configured tensorflow with CUDA and then ran `bazel` as follows:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --config=numa
```

The error looks like something trivial, however, I'm totally unfamiliar with `bazel`. Could you help?

Apparently [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41057) they speak about the same issue but there is no solution yet.

Comment: This doesn't address your issue but TF2 built with CUDA 11 is available in the 20.06 [ngc container](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tensorflow-release-notes/rel_20-06.html#rel_20-06).